# Syntax Error in Express (Node) when Deploying Angular App: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

So, I have built an angular apps and when i did `ng build --prod` it went **successful**, **no errors** and **no warnings** at all.

What i plan is to copy all those generated files from build process into `views/` directory in my Node Express server, it will become like following

```
--server
---server.js
---views/
----index.html
----main.000000000.js
----runtime.000000.js
----styles.000000.css
----icon_000000.png
----etc (all generated files from `ng build --prod`)
```

What i put inside `server.js` was a simple app like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `views/index.html`));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port);

console.log('Server has started on port ' + port);
```

When i hit `localhost:3001/` it will give **many** errors of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, the error basically means that when the browser request those (some) static files it will be responded with `index.html` by the server, instead of correlated static files.

How i fix is using code below:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const allowed = [
  '.js',
  '.css',
  '.png',
  '.jpg',
  '.gif',
  '.ico',
  '.svg',
  '.woff',
  '.eot',
  '.ttf',
];

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   if (allowed.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(`views/${req.url}`));
   } else {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
   }
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port);

console.log('Server has started on port ' + port);
```

However the solution above is dirty, like we have to hard code every non `.html` static files that were inside `/dist`, i need another solution here, how to solve this without hard code every static file extension? am i doing something wrong during angular `ng build --prod`?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using return while sending response?                                                 
            return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, `views/index.html`)); in your code above.

Comment: my bad, even if i remove the `return` keyword the error still the same

Comment: Can you share your server directory structure because above there is no views directory.

Comment: sorry i already revised my question it  should be `views` not `dist`